# Why the configFn of angular.module is not optional?

Tags: angularjs

When we call `angular.module('app-name',[])`, why the second parameter `configFn` is not optional? Why it is not simply set as an empty `array` if not provided?

===update===

The second parameter is not `configFn` but `requires`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of, the signature is `angular.module(moduleName, requires, configFn)`, where the second and third are optional.

The question is that this method is overloaded. If you pass a `requires`, then you will create a new module. If you omit the second and third params, Angular retrieves an already loaded module.

The empty array is telling angular that your module called `app-name` has no dependencies in other modules. If you omit the empty array, Angular would try to retrieve the module `app-name`, and would fail, as this module has not been declared yet.

From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module):

> requires(optional) – {Array.=} – **If specified** then new module is being created. **If unspecified** then the the module is being retrieved for further configuration.

Comment: That is poor API. Why can't it be `angular.getModule`.

Comment: @CaioToOn Thanks for your answer. Can anybody explain what is the principle behind this API design? I have made the mistake for several times by missed the `[]` parameter.

Comment: @manojlds, it's common on JS API (like jQuery `data` and `css`) that getters are a overloaded version of setters, maybe this is what they had in mind when creating it, except that `angular.module` is not a setter :). @eagle, I don't know if I got your point, but if you're asking why would someone retrieve a module after it has been created, it's because you usually tear your code down in several files, so the first one register the module, and the others retrieve it and configure its directives, controllers... if you're asking about the API design, I don't know, but those were my two cents.

Comment: @eagle, not begging for points here, but why you believe this question doesn't answer you question anymore?

Comment: @CaioToOn It definitely answered my question. Thanks! Sorry for accepting late.